# How do we use the latest API features?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing an extension for VSCode, at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api there are some functions which do not seem to be available yet:

vscode.window.withProgress(...)
vscode.window.showSaveDialog(...)

I have the following on my depedencies:

> "vscode": "^1.1.14"

I am missing something to be able to use certain API functions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to upgrade vscode dependency version
`vscode.window.withProgress` was introduced with vscode 1.12 (https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12)

As vscode try to keep itself updated you can use the latest vscode(1.21.1) version or 2-3 months old(1.17.0)

The vscode version needs to be changed on the packages.json "engines" section.